# Completion handler for Firebase Realtime DB lookup when one function needs the value of a previous function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui, completionhandler

I have the following code that fetches a schedule

```
func fetchSchedule(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    
    scheduleRef.queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: true).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        self.schedule = []
        
        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            // Null
            
        } else {
            
            for child in snapshot.children {
                        
                if let snapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                        
                   let schedule = Schedule(snapshot: snapshot) {
                            
                       self.schedule.append(schedule)
                            
                }
                        
            }

        }

    })
    
}
```

The above get the current schedule but what I am unclear on is that i need that value to then call the next function call which get the associated games for that schedule on the .onAppear() of the view in SwiftUI

```
func getGames() {

    scheduleStore.fetchSchedule()
    //
    gameStore.fetchGames(weekId: self.scheduleStore.schedule[0].weekId)

}
```

the gameStore.fetchGames always returns null, likely because it has not finished processing the fetchSchedule function?

How do I ensure the first function finishes before it calls the fetchGames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a completion handler built into your function signature on `fetchSchedule`, but you aren't using it.

```
func fetchSchedule(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    
    scheduleRef.queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: true).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        self.schedule = []
        
        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            // Null
            
        } else {
            
            for child in snapshot.children {
                        
                if let snapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                        
                   let schedule = Schedule(snapshot: snapshot) {
                            
                       self.schedule.append(schedule)
                            
                }
                        
            }

            completion() //<-- Here

        }

    })
    
}
```

Then,

```
func getGames() {
    scheduleStore.fetchSchedule(completion: {
       gameStore.fetchGames(weekId: self.scheduleStore.schedule[0].weekId)
    })
}
```

You're not showing all of your code, but you may also have something broken between `self.schedule`, which you set in `fetchSchedule`, and `self.scheduleStore`, you you send to `fetchGames` -- make sure you've only got one place you're storing data -- should it be `self.schedule` in both places?

---

**Update, based on comments**

This code is approximate, since I don't have access to your types, but it should get you started:

```
func fetchSchedule(completion: @escaping ([Schedule]) -> ()) {
    
    scheduleRef.queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: true).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        
        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            // Null
            
        } else {
            
            let schedules = snapshot.children.compactMap { child in
               if let snapshot = child as? DataSnapshot, let schedule = Schedule(snapshot: snapshot) {
                  return schedule
               }
               return nil
            }

            completion(schedules)

        }

    })
    
}
```

```
func getGames() {
    scheduleStore.fetchSchedule { schedules in
       gameStore.fetchGames(weekId: schedules[0].weekId)
    }
}
```

Comment: i knew i was missing something... your solution worked! Thx for the assist!!!

Comment: You could also look into refactoring even further by passing the `Schedule` as a parameter into the completion handler. Also, you could use a "trailing closure" syntax for `fetchSchedule` if you want. But, those are just refinements -- glad it is working as-is.

Comment: i tried earlier and it said that it was too early to mark response as answer, i have now. Can you elaborate further on how to pass the `Schedule` as the parameter? I'm not sure i understand , but if you can show that version as part of ur solution able as well?

Comment: Updated -- should be enough to get the idea across, at least